# Cordova FileUploadOptions params not posted on iOS

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, ios8.4

Using an app built using build.phonegap.com I'm finding that the FileUploadOptions.params values aren't being posted - iOS (8.4.1) only posts the file multipart data. This isn't a server side error as I've watched the POST using tcpdump/Wireshark and netcat.

Using:

- PhoneGap v.3.7.0
- Ionic Framework v.1.0.1
- AngularJS v.1.3.13

This is the code that is used to upload a test file. It generates a temporary file and attempts to upload it. The question is, have I mucked something up, or is this a bona fide bug?

```js
  $scope.doUploadTest = function() {
    var q = $q.defer();
    var promise = q.promise;

    var text = "Test file content: " + new Date();

    $window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, text.length, function(fs) {
      q.resolve(fs);
    }, function(err) {
      q.reject(err);
    });

    promise
    .then(function(fs) {
      var qFile = $q.defer();

      fs.root.getFile("upload.tmp", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(entry) {
        qFile.resolve(entry);
      }, function(err) {
        qFile.reject(err);
      });

      return qFile.promise;
    })
    .then(function(entry) {
      console.log("got file: " + entry.nativeURL);

      var qWriter = $q.defer();

      entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
        qWriter.resolve({writer: writer, entry: entry});
      }, function(err) {
        qWriter.reject(err);
      });

      return qWriter.promise;
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      var qWrite = $q.defer();

      response.writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        qWrite.resolve(response.entry);
      };

      response.writer.write(text);

      return qWrite.promise;
    })
    .then(function(entry) {
      $scope.error = entry;

      var qUpload = $q.defer();

      var options = new FileUploadOptions();
      options.params = {
        Value: {
          list: [1, 2, 3],
          text: "foo bar baz",
          number: 1234
        }
      };
      options.fileKey = "thefile";
      options.fileName = entry.name;
      options.mimeType = "text/plain";
      options.chunkedMode = false;
      options.headers = {
        "X-Upload": (new Date()).toString()
      };


      var ft = new FileTransfer();
      ft.upload(entry.nativeURL, "http://192.168.0.30:9100/", function(success) {
        entry.remove();
        qUpload.resolve(success);
      }, function(err) {
        entry.remove();
        qUpload.reject(err);
      }, options);

      // Abort after 3 seconds
      $timeout(function() {
        console.log("Aborting upload - timed out");
        ft.abort();
      }, 3000);

      return qUpload.promise;
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log("Upload succeeded");
      $scope.error = response;
    })

    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Upload failed");
      $scope.error = err;
    });
    ;


  };
```

The request made on an iPhone 6 (iOS v.8.4.1) is as follows:

```
    POST / HTTP/1.1
    Host: 192.168.0.30:9100
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=+++++org.apache.cordova.formBoundary
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    X-Upload: Tue Sep 01 2015 12:12:49 GMT+0100 (BST)
    Connection: keep-alive
    Accept: */*
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12H321 (5348809648)
    Content-Length: 261
    Accept-Language: en-us
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

    --+++++org.apache.cordova.formBoundary
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="thefile"; filename="upload.tmp"
    Content-Type: text/plain
    Content-Length: 58

    Test file content: Tue Sep 01 2015 12:12:49 GMT+0100 (BST)
    --+++++org.apache.cordova.formBoundary--
```

On a Motorola Moto X (2nd gen, Android 5.1) the request is this:

```
    POST / HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=+++++
    X-Upload: Tue Sep 01 2015 12:52:24 GMT+0100 (BST)
    User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1; XT1092 Build/LPE23.32-25.1)
    Host: 192.168.0.30:9100
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    Content-Length: 289

    --+++++
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Value"

    {"list":[1,2,3],"text":"foo bar baz","number":1234}
    --+++++
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="thefile"; filename="upload.tmp"
    Content-Type: text/plain

    Test file content: Tue Sep 01 2015 12:52:23 GMT+0100 (BST)
    --+++++--
```

Comment: Posted bug report apache.org: [CB-9600](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9600)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the params object can only contain **literal** properties, and **not objects**. The [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileUploadOptions) only uses string values, but doesn't explicitly say that objects are unsupported.

This is further complicated by the fact that on Android the plugin serialises the object as a JSON string, whereas on iOS the plugin silently dumps it.

So, the solution is simply to serialise the data first:

```js
  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.params = {
    Value: JSON.stringify({
      list: [1, 2, 3],
      text: "foo bar baz",
      number: 1234
    })
  };
```